# How to prevent multiple reaction by Google Cloud VM instances for one event from Firebase database?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

**The problem:** doSomething() function, is invoked twice (by each running VM instance).

How can I react for each event by only one VM instance?

Node.js script at Google cloud platform:

```
function listenForNotificationRequests() {
    var requests = ref.child('some_node');
    requests.on('child_added', function(requestSnapshot) {
        var request = requestSnapshot.val();
        doSomething(  
           request.type,
           function() {
               requestSnapshot.ref.remove();
           });
    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to use firebase-queue, which covers this and many other scenarios: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue

Answer (score 1):

[firebase-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue/blob/master/docs/guide.md) solves your problem, as @Frank's comment pointed.

> Multiple queue workers can be initialized on multiple machines and
>   Firebase-Queue will ensure that only one worker is processing a single
>   queue task at a time.